# Abstracting Lists in Dr. Racket

Tags: racket, abstraction

Currently, I have a function *item counts* that is meant to count the number of elements in a string and order them into pairs if it occurs once or more.

```
(check-expect
 (item-counts
  (cons "hello"
        (cons "hey"
              (cons "hello" '())))
   equal?)
 (cons "hello" 2
       (cons "hey" 1) '()))

(check-expect
 (item-counts
  (cons #true
        (cons #false
              (cons #true '())))
  equal?)
 (cons #true 2
       (cons #false 1 '())))

(define (item-counts lop ef)
  (cond
    [(empty? (rest lop))
     (first lop)]
    [(cons? (rest lop))
     (if
      (ef (first lop) (item-counts (rest lop) ef))) ... ???
```

As shown by the tests, I wish to add a number to the existing list if one of the elements of this list occurs more than once. I used the *equal?* function to identify the number of times an element occurs, but I am lost on how to add the number to the existing list as well as condense the repeating elements when producing a new list. I have tried using the *append* function but it creates a list in a different format **( (list (list) )**.

Comment: `cons` only takes 2 arguments but you give it three in multiple occations. `(list 1 2 3)` ==  `'(1 2 3)` == `(cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 '())))` of which the last reflects tha  actual  way lists are constructed.

Comment: If you were to do the same with the list `(1 2 1 2 3 4)` and you were really nearsighted, thus only could look at one element at a time. How would you do it? One way is to take the first element `1`, then count the rest of the same element and then do another iteration where you remove that element. Then you can `(cons (cons 1 2) (iterm-counts '(2 2 3 4))` right?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is self-learning, for a class, etc. I know there are standard HtDP ways to do this, recipes, etc. But I don't know these things, sorry. What I will say is that Racket is quite easy to prototype things. You can just describe your problem and don't think too much about the details. I usually like to start in the middle.

For example:

At some point in the middle of execution you will have strings yet to examine and an association list of the strings examined so far. Then your task is 1) if there are no more strings to get, we're done, otherwise 2) get the next string, add it to the table, and continue because we're not done.

```
(define (build-assoc from-string current-assoc)
  (if (done? from-string)
      current-assoc
      (let ((first-string (get-first-string from-string)))
        (let ((result-table (add-string first-string current-assoc))
              (result-string (drop-first-string from-string)))
          (build-assoc result-string
                       result-table)))))
```

Maybe you don't use this procedure in the end. But it's a picture of what you're doing, and it suggests what sort of helper procedures you will need to finish your quest. Give yourself a fighting chance and just use DrRacket to outline your problem. When you see it, then maybe it gives you some ideas how to answer the questions. DrRacket helpfully points out all your unanswered questions like "done?: unbound identifier in: done?" Ah yes, how do we know we're done, good question DrRacket. Well you see, I was given this list of strings, so...